# Reachability Classes Issue iOS8

Tags: ipad, ios8, reachability

i am using latest reachability classes ver 3.5 of apple.my issue is when i switch off wifi the reachability classes take some time to give actual status."kReachabilityChangedNotification" notification is fired after some delay.this issue is coming on iOS 8.1.1 iPad air

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a thread-blocking issue: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/issues/74

Comment: Thanks , great answer